# finding the index of a variable in a nested list

Tags: python, syntax

```
def total_sales(sales_table, product):
    if product in sales_table[0]:
        return sum(list(zip(*sales_table[1:]))[sales_table[0].index(product)])
    return 'Product not found'
```

Hi could someone explain 1. what the * is doing after the `zip()` and 2. why there is no comma or break between the two elements in the `sum()`

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through nested lists, I usually use For loops.

Check this site for more info about ways to iterate through lists in python:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-a-list-in-python/

To get the index of a variable in a list (after iterating correctly through all your nested lists), use .index(element, start, end). This will return the index of the desired element you are searching for.

For more information about .index()

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index

The zip() function returns a zip object, which is an iterator of tuples where the first item in each passed iterator is paired together, and then the second item in each passed iterator are paired together etc.

If the passed iterators have different lengths, the iterator with the least items decides the length of the new iterator.

[https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/#:~:text=Python's%20zip()%20function%20is,%2C%20sets%2C%20and%20so%20on](https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/#:%7E:text=Python%27s%20zip()%20function%20is,%2C%20sets%2C%20and%20so%20on).

The sum(iterable, start) function returns a number, the sum of all items in an iterable.

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sum

Example:

```
numbers = [2.5, 3, 4, -5]

# start parameter is not provided
numbers_sum = sum(numbers)
print(numbers_sum)

# start = 10
numbers_sum = sum(numbers, 10)
print(numbers_sum)

# 4.5
# 14.5
```

The * can also be used for unpacking the containers. The easiest example is that we have data in the form of a list, tuple or dict, and a function take variable arguments:

```
from functools import reduce

primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]

def product(*numbers):
    p = reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, numbers)
    return p 

product(*primes)
# 30030

product(primes)
# [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
```

Because the product() take the variable arguments, we need to unpack the our list data and pass it to that function. In this case, if we pass the primes as *primes, every elements of the primes list will be unpacked, then stored in list called numbers. If pass that list primes to the function without unpacking, the numbers will has only one primes list not all elements of primes.

Answer (score 0):

At first there the * is for unpacking the list next to it, you can check the python syntax for the * and learn how it's used, and the other question u had, There are no comma in sum() because of it have a list() inside it, And sum() takes a list at sums it's up and return the sum of it.